# Getting `ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 1) vs ())` error

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to train my model and receiving this error when I call the `fit()` method.
Any ideas on why is this failing to run?

```py
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

df = pd.read_csv('labeled_tweets_processed.csv')
labels = df.pop('class')
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df, labels))

for x, y in dataset.take(1):
  print(x, y)

import numpy as np

import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow as tf

tfds.disable_progress_bar()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

train_dataset = dataset.take(10000)
test_dataset = dataset.skip(10000)

BUFFER_SIZE = 10000
BATCH_SIZE = 32

train_dataset.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

VOCAB_SIZE = 1000
encoder = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
    max_tokens=VOCAB_SIZE)
encoder.adapt(train_dataset.map(lambda text, label: text))

vocab = np.array(encoder.get_vocabulary()).flatten()
vocab[:20]

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    encoder,
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
        input_dim=len(encoder.get_vocabulary()),
        output_dim=64,
        # Use masking to handle the variable sequence lengths
        mask_zero=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data=test_dataset, epochs=10)
```

On the last command I receive the following error:
`ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 1) vs ())`

Any ideas why is this happening?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'texts': ['Some text', 'Some text', 'Some text', 'Some text', 'Some text'],
                          'class': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]})

labels = df.pop('class')
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df, labels))

VOCAB_SIZE = 1000
encoder = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
    max_tokens=VOCAB_SIZE)
encoder.adapt(dataset.map(lambda text, label: text))

BUFFER_SIZE = 2
BATCH_SIZE = 2

train_dataset = dataset.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    encoder,
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
        input_dim=len(encoder.get_vocabulary()),
        output_dim=64,
        # Use masking to handle the variable sequence lengths
        mask_zero=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=10)
```

Comment: Will run it in a bit and will come back to your right after @AloneTogether

Comment: I confirm that this worked, I don't know what I didn't do correctly though? Any chances that you could explain?

Comment: Check this in your code and compare it with mine: `train_dataset.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)`